# How to change and increase shadow color of Floating action button in native script

Tags: nativescript

I'm using the plugin nativescript-floatingactionbutton for FAB and I'm not getting how to increase or decrease its shadow brightness and its elevation.

i itried something like this,

```
.fab-button-action {
    margin: 20;
    height: 60;
    width: 60;
    background-color: rgba(192, 89, 5, 0.938);
    horizontal-align: right;
    border-width: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    elevation: 10;
}
```

with no result.  I need answer for Android

Comment: It's `android-elevation` not just `elevation`.

Comment: @Manoj Its working, but how to increase shadow density as it is very dim. even i want to change shadow color to dark orange color.

Comment: Refer the docs, you should use `android-dynamic-elevation-offset` for shadow density. You can not change shadow color alone, at least thats a limitation. You might be able to do it with some native code though.

Comment: @Manoj i don't know about android and java i know only nativescript. can you give link of docs where these css properties is given.

Comment: You could simply Google it, here you go -https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling